# How to use xarray to group by time and then run a bin function on the groups?

Tags: python, pandas-groupby, python-xarray

I have a multidimensional 'mean direction of total ocean swell' (mdts), netCDF data set.  The dimensions are `time` (in hours), `latitude`, and `longitude`.  I simply wish to group the hourly data by day and then for each day, for each lat/lon grid, determine which of 16 predefined directional bins contains the most hours (maximum could be 24).  The direction value associated with the bin with the most hours, for each lat/lon grid, would then be assigned as the direction for that particular day, for each lat/lon grid.  I'm applying a custom function to the `groupby` command and that is where the error is occurring.  I think I'm not understanding what is being passed to the function.

**Note:** each netCDF file represents 1979-2019 for one month.  Therefore, I'm using `groupby` instead of `resample` as `resample` adds the 11 other months not in the file.  I also first converted all the hours to 00:00 so that `groupby` would work for grouping by days.

Note: my actual code is set to loop through several netCDF files.  I've simplified it here for one file.
My simplified code:

```
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr
        
ifile = 'mean_direction_total_swell_Nov_1979_2019_hourly.nc'
        
# min, max, and center values of angle direction bins
min = [348.75,  11.25,  33.75,  56.25,  78.75, 101.25, 123.75, 146.25, 168.75, 191.25, 213.75, 236.25, 258.75, 281.25, 303.75, 326.25]
max = [ 11.25,  33.75,  56.25,  78.75, 101.25, 123.75, 146.25, 168.75, 191.25, 213.75, 236.25, 258.75, 281.25, 303.75, 326.25, 348.75]
dir = [   0.0,   22.5,   45.0,   67.5,   90.0,  112.5,  135.0,  157.5,  180.0,  202.5,  225.0,  247.5,  270.0,  292.5,  315.0,  337.5]
    
# custom function that I think is causing the problem    
def bins(x):
    bins_n = np.zeros([16], dtype=int)
        
    # North bin requires 'or' statement
    if(x >= min[0] or x < max[0]): bins_n[0] = bins_n[0] + 1
        
    # other bins require 'and' statement
    for i in range(1,16,1): # bins
        if(x >= min[i] and x < max[i]):
            bins_n[i] = bins_n[i] + 1
            break
    slot = np.argmax(bins_n)
        
    return dir[slot]
    
   
idatanc = xr.open_dataset(ifile)              
idata = idatanc['mdts']                          
    
idata.coords['time'] = idata.time.dt.floor('1D') # setting all hourly values to 0000 
idata_dy = idata.groupby("time").apply(bins)
```

What gets returned.  Note: this error is based on the looping program for multiple netCDF files so it may not correspond exactly to the code above.  The errors are still the same.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-216-82adffe45690>", line 9, in <module>
    idata_dy = idata.groupby("time").apply(bins)

  File "C:\Users\TWHawk\Anaconda3\envs\tim_python36\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\groupby.py", line 815, in apply
    return self.map(func, shortcut=shortcut, args=args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\TWHawk\Anaconda3\envs\tim_python36\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\groupby.py", line 800, in map
    return self._combine(applied, shortcut=shortcut)

  File "C:\Users\TWHawk\Anaconda3\envs\tim_python36\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\groupby.py", line 819, in _combine
    applied_example, applied = peek_at(applied)

  File "C:\Users\TWHawk\Anaconda3\envs\tim_python36\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\utils.py", line 183, in peek_at
    peek = next(gen)

  File "C:\Users\TWHawk\Anaconda3\envs\tim_python36\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\groupby.py", line 799, in <genexpr>
    applied = (maybe_wrap_array(arr, func(arr, *args, **kwargs)) for arr in grouped)

  File "<ipython-input-215-3d060f71ca15>", line 6, in bins
    if(x >= min[0] or x < max[0]): bins_n[0] = bins_n[0] + 1

  File "C:\Users\TWHawk\Anaconda3\envs\tim_python36\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\common.py", line 119, in __bool__
    return bool(self.values)

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: Without a sample of your data we can't test your code properly. However, it seems to me that the problem is with the `or` operator. Try using the `np.logical_or`, like `np.logical_or(x >= min[0], x < max[0])`. If it works for you, do the same for the `and` operator you have a few lines below

Comment: @Ralubrusto  Thanks!  I'm editing my code based on your idea.  In the meantime, here is a link to the actual data file if you want to have a look.  https://www.dropbox.com/s/tgbry1z6jgot816/mean_direction_total_swell_Nov_1979_2019_hourly.nc?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't check  the results all the way but I think the code bellows does what you need:

```
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr
from scipy import stats

def func(x, axis):
    mode, count = np.apply_along_axis(stats.mode, axis, x)
    return mode.squeeze()

infile = 'mean_direction_total_swell_Nov_1979_2019_hourly.nc'

ds = xr.open_dataset(infile)

# make sure range is 0 <= x < 360
ds['mdts'] = np.mod(ds['mdts'], 360)

# bin the data in 16 directions (17 actually, North appears as the first and
# last bin)
step = 360 / 16
centers = np.r_[np.r_[0: 360: step], 0]
edges = np.r_[0, np.r_[step / 2: 360: step], 360]

ds['mdts_binned_idx'] = (ds['mdts'].dims, np.digitize(ds['mdts'], edges))

ds['mdts_binned'] = (ds['mdts'].dims, centers[ds['mdts_binned_idx'] - 1])

# apply stats.mode to get the modal (most common) value in each day
ds2 = xr.Dataset()
ds2['mdts_mode_1d'] = ds['mdts_binned'].resample(time='1D').reduce(func)
```

Comment: Thanks!  This worked!  I did modify my personal code a bit to create 16 bins and to convert the date coordinate to just a day format (w/o hours) so I could use the `groupby` command as noted in my original post.